# Activate Button in other application

Tags: vb.net, winapi

i wan to active start button in other app, i use spy ++ to check the button styles, i c bs_pushbutton. i try to use win api to do it.i tried WM_SETFOCUS and enter key to do it, but fail

these is my code

```
    Dim hwnd As Int32 = apiFindWindowEx(HWND_DESKTOP, 0, Nothing, "Open File -     Security Warning")
    Dim cwnd As Int32 = apiFindWindowEx(hwnd, 0, Nothing, "&Run")
    Dim i As Integer = SendMessage(cwnd, BS_PUSHBUTTON, 0, 0)
```

i declare `BS_PUSHBUTTON = &H1&` 
it is correct value for BS_PUSHBUTTON ???

how can i run the app button event??

Comment: We know that you need help, otherwise you would not be posting here. Please use an appropriate title.

Comment: if this code reflects what you actually want to do: there are better and easier ways to disable this warning: run gpedit.msc, go to Local Computer Policy->User Configuration->Administrative Templates->Windows Components->Attachment Manager and add the 'safe' file types; apart from that, this has nothing to do with C# and your title is a bit harsh

Comment: This is a classic XY problem as @stijn has correctly identified. Your question will be improved when you explain why you want to automate pressing this button since it's almost surely the case that there is a trivial way to avoid writing hacky code like this.

Comment: BS_PUSHBUTTON is not a message it's a button style, after you have the handle for the button you'd be sending a [`BM_CLICK`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb775985%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to it (if the dialog is the active window).

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear exactly what you're asking for in this question. I'm not sure whether you're attempting to enable a button or emulate a click to it.

Anyway, for the former you simply need to use [EnableWindow()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646291%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

```
EnableWindow( cwnd, true );
```

Or alternatively:

```
Button_Enable( cwnd, true );
```

For the latter you can use [SetActiveWindow()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646311%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [BM_CLICK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb775985%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

```
SetActiveWindow( hwnd );
SendMessage( cwnd, BM_CLICK, 0, 0 );
```